# Shapely Split a LineString based on Intersections with other LineStrings

Tags: python, geometry, intersection, shapely, linestring

I'm new to using Shapely, and I have some question. I have a LineString and I wish to split it based on intersections of other LineStrings.

If the intersection turns out to be a single point, then we can simply use the following code to obtain a GeometryCollection of LineStrings split at that intersection point:

```
ip = ls.intersection(other_ls) # assuming ip here is a single Point()
ops.split(ls, ip)
```

Kind of like this, where our observed LineString is the blue one and the other LineString that splits it is red:
[image]

However, if the intersection of two LineStrings is also another LineString (i.e., a shared path), then running the following code:

```
ops.split(ls, other_ls) # assuming that the intersection is also a LineString
```

returns an error:

```
ValueError: Input geometry segment overlaps with the splitter.
```

The picture I would like to present here is this:
[image]

where again, the blue LineString is our observed and the red LineString is the one to split the blue one. The resultant would be a GeometryCollection of three LineStrings but of course it is also possible to obtain a GeometryCollection of two LineStrings as a result just depending on where the red LineString is situated. I wish to be able to do this, but using `ops.split()` does not seem to work.

But ultimately, I wish to generalize this as there can be many other LineStrings that overlap (i.e., intersect on many LineStrings), such as the following picture:
[image]

But I am not exactly sure how to do it correctly. Here is a rough pseudocode that I came up with but I am not sure if it is right or whether it would be efficient when it is implemented. I'm not really looking for a top-notch solution when it comes to runtime. But at least something that works.

```
ls = observed_linestring
other_linestrings = list_consisting_of_other_linestrings
for ol in other_linestrings:
    intersections = ol.intersection(ls)
    point_intersections = [x for x in intersections if x is a Point]
    for point in point_intersections:
        splits = ops.split(ls, point)
return splits
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [unary_union](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union) ([Planar Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph))

> LineStrings will get fully dissolved and noded. Duplicate Points will get merged.

Original 4 lines

[image]

```
from shapely.ops import unary_union
lines = [line1,line2,line3,line4]
result = unary_union(lines)
```

The result is a MuliLineString with 13 lines

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, I just figured an algorithm without unary_union. The problem if I use that is that I will get extra unneeded linestrings from the MultiLineString. In the picture I drew, I only need linestrings belonging to the blue one. Here's how I did it: (1) Find all intersection pts between blue linestring and all other linestrings. (2) Find all intersection pts between any 2 linestrings that also intersect with the blue linestring (pairwise). (3) Create a MultiPoint of such pts, & use it a splitter for ops.split(blue,mp). I'll get a GeometryCollection of linestrings.